# can I download Nodejs modules as javascript files?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to use the [crypto module](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) from nodejs but I don't want to use the entire framework.

Is where any way to simply download the js files for a particular library that I would normally `require` if I were working in node. If I had the Javascript file I could just include it with my project, and that's good enough for this one.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, always check github. Source code is found in the component folder: https://github.com/sytelus/CryptoJS

On a side note: I'd highly recommend using npm in general practice. Along with dependency fixes/testing/etc it makes it really simple to manage projects and keep them up to date.

Comment: The Node.js crypto source can be found => [https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/crypto.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/crypto.js)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the [Stanford Javascript Crypto Library](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/) could be a useful "node.js free" alternative for you. Here's a direct link to the [minified source](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/sjcl.js) you could drop in to start playing with the API. While basic, observe the following proof of concept...

```
let pw = sjcl.random.randomWords(256 / 32);
let ct = sjcl.encrypt(pw, 'sooperstrong!');
let pt = sjcl.decrypt(pw, ct);

console.log(pt); // sooperstrong!
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/o8sxrr3d/) - demo